# Using each right to pass parameters to a kdb function

Tags: kdb

I have the following code that does not work:

```
fun { [h; d]
 h(anotherFun; d)
}

h: hopen(`hparam)
d: (2013.06.01, 2013.06.02)
h,/:fun d
```

What do I need to do to call fun with h and each element of d? The diagnostic from q is cryptic to say the least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like h and elements of d are your two arguments so you can try

```
h fun/: d
```

Comment: What confused me was the comma in the reference examples: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/SlashColon. Do you know why comma is used there?

Comment: comma is the function used in that example. If you look at the output it generates lists with 1 in front and 1-15 at end.

Comment: I see, comma in this case is the function itself. Why to name a system function 'comma' anyway?!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest would be create projection with constant argument and just call it for each argument from the list

```
 fun[h;] each d
```